# How to place text on a diagonal line?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, css-transforms

[image: Text on a diagonal line]

Hey guyz, I guess you got my concept by seeing the above picture. I'm unable to place diagonal line behind the text and it should get masked by the content placed on it. I wanted it in pure css. Background should be visible through the text.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to explain what it is *exactly* you're trying to do. Right now, I'm struggling to see what it is...

Comment: @jbutler483 and, anyway, 2 upvotes ...

Comment: @vals: Nothing surprises me on SO anymore...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a rotated pseudo element. Make it 1px wide and make the lines with top/bottom borders :

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url('https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6083/6055581292_d94c2d90e3.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 130px auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -120px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  border-top: 120px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 120px solid #000;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(8deg);
  transform: rotate(8deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec luctus condimentum mi sit amet iaculis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Maecenas eleifend commodo rutrum.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this-

```css
body{background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Kv22GCi.png');}
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px; left: 45%;
  width: 1px; height: 100%;
  border-top: 120px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 120px solid #000;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(8deg);
  transform: rotate(8deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
   <h2>dsfsd jf fkljdsfjdsj</h2>
   <p>Loream ipsum dolor shit amet</p>
  </div>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes, I got stuck here. Am using the image as Background of whole page. So, I cannot use color behind text.

Comment: Sorry to say this, But I have no need to copy your answer.(thanks for not downvote.)

Comment: I appreciate for your answer, but I am copying anybody. please @srikanth_naalla accept web-tiki's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do using pseudo selectors **:after** or **:before**

Download this [png](/questions/tagged/png) image for background https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBjE4.png
[image]

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 548px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBjE4.png);
  padding: 50px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif
}
/*For the diagonal line*/

.container:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  top: 0;
  left: 70px;
  z-index: -1;
  -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(10deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
  transform: rotate(10deg)
}
h1 {
  font-size: 50px
}
p {
  font-size: 22px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>About Us.</h1>

  <p>"Lorem ipsum sit amet.Lorem ipsum sit amet.Lorem ipsum sit amet.Lorem ipsum sit amet.Lorem ipsum sit amet.Lorem ipsum sit amet.Lorem ipsum sit amet."
    <p/>
</div>
```

Comment: you may want to include prefixing for your transform for cross browser compatibility,

Comment: @jbutler483 Added vendor prefixes now??